# I can't get my chat in an Iframe to bring back content when user changes page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, chat

I have a chat that displays in an iframe in my site.
Chat is running in chat.A.com (a different server) and my site is in A.com. I am displaying the chat in A.com by using an iframe (iframe.src = "chat.A.com").
When user changes page, the chat reloads and start from beginning. I have tried getting the contentdocument of the original iframe and trying to write it to another iframe and it still refreshes.
Have anyone dealt with something like this before?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your chat backend would have to load the old chat and fill it into the iframe when it loads, you can't carry the content around with you as they navigate through the frontend.

Comment: @colins Can you explain more what you mean by my chat backend will have to load the old chat. How do i let it know to load the old chat?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're using for chat, which you haven't told us anything about.